# Is it possible to put JavaScript code into a JS file through Python?

Tags: javascript, python, file

```
with open("C:scripts/CUAppVersion.js", 'a') as file:
file.write("if [CUID] = -1 then"
    "function GetCUID() { return 0; }"
"else"
    "function GetCUID() { return [CUID] });")
```

That is my code and it succesfully  puts the JS into the JS file but it puts it on one line rather than as I typed it above. I am aware that my JS code isn't fully correct I do need to fix it.

How do I put that code into the JS file with the correct layout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use multiline strings.

```
with open("C:/scripts/CUAppVersion.js", 'a') as file:
    file.write("""
if [CUID] = -1 then
    function GetCUID() { return 0; }
else
    function GetCUID() { return [CUID] });
""".strip())
```

Comment: Thank you that did the job! :D

Answer (score 1):

What about adding some endlines `\n`?

```
with open("C:scripts/CUAppVersion.js", 'a') as file:
    file.write("if [CUID] = -1 then\n"
        "function GetCUID() { return 0; }\n"
        "else\n"
        "function GetCUID() { return [CUID] });\n")
```

Comment: Thanks a mill, can't believe I didn't think of that xD

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` to the end of every line.

```
with open("C:scripts/CUAppVersion.js", 'a') as file:
file.write("if [CUID] = -1 then\n"
    "function GetCUID() { return 0; }\n"
"else\n"
    "function GetCUID() { return [CUID] });\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I over looked such a simple solution.